# Store previous commands only once in Cygwin Terminal

Tags: terminal, cygwin

When typing commands in the Cygwin Terminal, if I enter the same command twice, it will be stored twice when I press the up arrow.

For example, if I enter `command1` once and `command2` twice, I have to press the up arrow twice to get back to `command1`. I want to configure it so that I only have to press up twice to get back to `command1`. Is this possible with the Cygwin Terminal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that you're talking about bash, the shell running the cygwin command line.

As explained [here](http://stefaanlippens.net/bashduplicates)

```
export HISTCONTROL=ignoredups
```

will achieve the effect you want.  Persisting this setting can be done via [.bashrc](http://cs.nyu.edu/~yap/prog/cygwin/FAQs.html#bashrc)